# How to bring information about a Docker image into the Artifactory build info with Gradle Jib and Artifactory plugin?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, jib

I want to create a Docker image with Gradle and the Jib plugin and bring it to Artifactory. The Docker image should be included in the Artifactory build info.

I can create the Docker image with the Jib Plugin. But how can I get the information about the Docker image into the Artifactory Buildinfo?

The relevant part of my gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "3.3.2"
    id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '5.1.6'
}

jib {
    from {
        image = "myRepo/$myBaseImage"       
    }
    to {
        image = "myRepo/myProject:${myTag}"
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://myRepo/artifactory/'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'myRepo'
        }
        clientConfig.info.setBuildNumber(project.version)
        defaults {
            publications ('ALL_PUBLICATIONS')
            publishBuildInfo = true
            publishArtifacts = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, after running `gradle jib` or actually `gradle jibDockerBuild`, you can find the `image digest` and the `image ID` at `build/jib-image.digest` and `build/jib-image.id` respectively.

---

Refer: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#outputpaths-closure

Answer (score 0):

To create the Docker image and upload it to Artifactory, you can refer to the guidelines provided here: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#using-jfrog-container-registry-jcr-or-jfrog-artifactory

Currently, the collection of build information for JIB is exclusively supported by the Jenkins Artifactory plugin. You can check out the [Maven JIB example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/maven-jib-example), which is applicable to Gradle as well.